# Instancing a Table from __tablename__ in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to instance a table with its tablename?

I've looked for in SQLAlchemy documentation and I couldn't find anything.

```
class A():
    __tablename__ = 'x'

newTable = Table('x')
```

Is possible something like this?

**This is a pseudo-language, not real Python code**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create_a.py

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'X'
    A_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    A_name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_example.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Insert_a.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from Create_a import A, Base, engine

Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()
print A.__tablename__ 
A.__tablename__ = A
new_A = A.__tablename__(A_name='new A')
session.add(new_A)
session.commit()
```

Were **A.__tablename__** is **X**

Comment: What is this line doing? `A.__tablename__ = A`

Comment: Here A.__tablename__ is the class variable referencing to the Class A. So now you can initialize an instance of class A using A.__tablename__

Answer (score 1):

Given some model `Foo`:

```py
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foos'
    ...
```

the associated table object can be accessed directly via the `__table__` attribute (provided that the entity has been mapped, for example via `Base.metadata.create_all`):

```py
tbl = Foo.__table__
```

If only the *value* of `Foo.__tablename__` is available the table can be retrieved using reflection:

```
tbl = sa.Table('foos', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
```